# Delta time in game development

Tags: c++, glfw

So im making a flappy bird clone, just to learn opengl. I've got a problem with delta time, value that im multiplying with delta time behaves differently depending on FPS.
This is the delta time code:

```
float lastTick = 0.0f;
float deltaTime = 0.0f;

inline void calculateDeltaTime(double time)
{
    deltaTime = (float)time - lastTick;
    lastTick = (float)time;
}
```

And this is how i call it in my game loop:

```
calculateDeltaTime(glfwGetTime());
```

I've tested it, when vsync is enabled i get the value around 0.0167 @ 60fps, which is right.

Over time i want my player to fall down, and this is how i implemented it, in the game loop.

```
fall += 0.3f * deltaTime;
m_Sprite->setPosition(math::vec3(m_Sprite->getPosition().x, m_Sprite->getPosition().y - fall, 0));
```

The player fall speed isnt the same when the fps is increased, at 60 it works great, when i disable vsync, at around 1500fps player instantly falls down, seems like the delta value isnt calculated properly, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try printing `time`/`deltaTime` for the `1500` fps case? That may help diagnose the issue. From a first look however it seems either an error with either the floating point arithmetic, or more likely the time resolution

Comment: Obligatory [fix your timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/).